# Persistent variables across files and differents executions in python over Windows are always initialized

Tags: python, variables, memory, share

I'm trying to share and update global variables in python, over Windows OS. I achieved this in Linux without any problem using a *config_file.py* with the default declarations of vars. Python's doc recommends this way:

https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#how-do-i-share-global-variables-across-modules

But, when I tried in Windows OS, globals vars are always inicialized. The code to invoke, update and use globals vars is:

File with vars declarations:

```
# globals_vars.py file
CREATED_MODELS = []
MODELS = {}
```

Class that calls and update global vars:

```
import globals_vars # File with global vars

class InferredModel():
    def __init__(self, model_name, model_weights, error):
        self.model_weights = model_weights
        self.model_name = model_name
        self.error = error
        
        # Se controla si ya se ha creado el modelo
        if model_name in globals_vars.CREATED_MODELS:
            print("Modelo ya existente en la BBDD")
            return
        else:
            print("Creando nuevo modelo")
            if self.weights_inference():
                globals_vars.CREATED_MODELS.append(model_name)
                globals_vars.MODELS[model_name] = \
                    {"float": self.inferred_weights, \
                     "fixed": self.fxd_inferred_weights}
```

I Know about h5 files to store variables, also .txt or database, but I need store variables in memory beacuse I have to store objects such ass buffers memory for large math calculus...
I'm using Spyder 4.1.5 and Conda in Windows 10.

Comment: The method shown in the documentation _does_ work on Windows (as it does on all OSs). Note that it's for retaining the values of variable during the same execution of the Python interpreter.

Comment: Thx @martineau . I've solved it. Only a problem in python's interpreter config.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the MRU been enable and Python's interpreter always recharge the modules... the option that should be disabled is in the image:

[image]